# Refactoring Old code from J# to  C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnodelist

I have some old J# code that I am moving to C#

```
  XmlNodeList itemTransferOutNodes = 
                 strXML.GetElementsByTagName("ItemTransferOut");
  XmlElement itemInfo = 
                 itemTransferOutNodes.Item(itemTrOutNodesCnt)
                                     .ChildNodes.Item(0)
                                     .get_Item("itemInfo");
```

I dont see in `C#` API of `XmlNodeList`  method called  `get_Item`.
To what I should change  `get_Item` in `c#`.

Thanks .

Comment: Can you add a sample of the XML you are using to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J# does not have support for properties like C# does, so they are "faked" by using methods instead. You can find more information on [that matter on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). If a C# object has a property named SomeProperty:

```
 public class Dummy {
      public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
 }
```

in J#, you'll have to call get_SomeProperty() and set_SomeProperty(string value):

```
 public class Dummy
 {
      private String someProperty;

      /** @property */
      public void set_SomeProperty(String val) { 
          someProperty = val; 
      }

      /** @property */
      public String get_SomeProperty() { 
          return someProperty; 
      }
 }
```

And the other way around is true.

If you find in J# a class method called get_xxx or set_xxx, it's most likely that in C#, the object has a property named xxx.

So basically, as others mentionned, you have to use the Item property in your code :

```
XmlNodeList itemTransferOutNodes = 
                  strXML.GetElementsByTagName("ItemTransferOut");

XmlElement itemInfo = 
                  itemTransferOutNodes.Item(itemTrOutNodesCnt)
                  .ChildNodes.Item(0).Item["itemInfo"];
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlElement itemInfo = itemTransferOutNodes.Item(itemTrOutNodesCnt)
                                          .ChildNodes
                                          .Item(0)["itemInfo"];
```

[XMLNode.Item documentation on MSDN](http://preview.library.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sss31aas%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, I would recommend [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

Without seeing your XML I guess it would be something like:

```
strXml.Root
      .Decendants("ItemTransferOut")
      .First(xele => xele.Name.LocalName == "itemInfo")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [XmlNode.Item Property (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sss31aas) . from msdn:

> Gets the first child element with the specified Name.